# Fanfiction about Harry Potter finally being reunited with his lost relatives

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

This story goes that Harry has ancient and noble houses that include Hogwarts. Harry has a relative that Dumbledore put to sleep (she is a woman; her name starts with 'A'), just because she is a powerful wizard (I forget if she is Lily's sister or Harry's older sister).

Harry Potter was in danger, then Hogwarts awakens his relatives to protect Harry. It includes politics. They all meet in Gringotts bank, and the goblin removes their blocks and magical binds.

It includes Remus and Sirius and the Weasley family and that is where Harry found out he has family, and that Harry was in the 3rd or 4th year, and that Ron has dyslexia. Hermione helps him and finally Harry's relatives put Dumbledore in place in Wizengamot.

Anyone recall this fanfic? I've been wanting to read it for years! If you know the title, I'll be glad!

Comment: How long ago did you read this? Do you remember what site? do you remember the rough length of the story? (like 100k+ words longhaul or like a oneshot or something inbetween?) Was it a series or just one long book? Any other random unique things that might make it easier to search for and find?